# copying portion of object array in Java

Tags: java

If I have an object array in Java `Car[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`. How would I make a copy of this array from index 2 to 7?

I thought about making a for loop

```
Car[] b = new Car[a.length - 2];

for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
  b[i - 2] = a[i];
}
```

Is there another way by using some of Java's built in Library? If there is, would it be more or less efficient than the for loop I proposed?

Comment: You can use Arrays.copyOfRange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `copyOfRange` of the `Arrays` class to copy certain ranges.

**sample:**

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 2, 7);
```

Method [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29)

```
copyOfRange(T[] original,
              int from,
              int to)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Arrays` class:

```
b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 2, 7);
```

Answer (score 4):

System arraycopy:

```
System.arraycopy(a, 2, b, 0, 5);
```

where b is your destination, starting from index 2, taking 5 (up to position 7)

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays#copyOfRange` - Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array.

```
java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(copyFrom, startindex, endIndex);
```

`Arrays#copyOfRange` method internally use `System#arraycopy`. [Source for reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOfRange%28boolean%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29)

AND alternatively you can use System utility it also.

`System#arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)` -

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Car[] splitArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, starting_index, end_index);
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I have an object array in Java Car[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. How would I make a copy of this array from index 2 to 7?

Use one of the `Arrays.copyOfRange()` methods like [`Arrays.copyOfRange(T[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29),

```
Car[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 2, 7);
```

From the Javadoc,

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array.

It is also possible to use [`System.arraycopy(Object,int,Object,int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29),

```
Car[] b = new Car[a.length - 2];
System.arraycopy(a, 2, b, 0, b.length);
```

And its Javadoc,

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array.

Answer (score 1):

CopiesofRange() of the Arrays seems to be a recommended method to perform a copy of a specified range into another array.

Signature

```
public static <T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original,
                  int from,
                  int to)
```

T is generic and can be replaced by any class or primary type of variables.